# Text to image on fly with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way or method to convert text (string) to image with javascript or jquery?
I cant find any way to do this.
Whats the best?

I don't want to use php or asp.net to do this.
Thanks for any tricks and help.

Comment: Why?  You can just insert text in your page and have it show as a wide variety of fonts.  You don't need it as an image to show it.

Comment: I need because I have some problem with unicode chars.

Comment: Then, you might as well give up doing this client side.  If you can't display your unicode text as normal text because of unicode issues, then I have no idea how you're going to draw it into an image client-side because that will have the same issues.  My guess is that you really just don't understand how to specify unicode text in HTML and select an appropriate font that has support for it.

Comment: That's not my problem, I have problem with Bi-directional text, but I found the solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `canvas` element and [draw text onto it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JUWrV/).

Comment: @NuLLeR Just as hint: canvas is a html5 element and not supported by every browser, yet. If you are using php / asp.net behind your application you can also create a page that renders a image dynamically. If you need a example pls let me know

Answer (score 0):

creating image from string with php

```
 <?php
 // Create a 100*30 image
 $im = imagecreate(100, 30);

 // White background and blue text 
 $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
 $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

 // Write the string at the top left
 imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, 'Hello world!', $textcolor);

 // Output the image
 header('Content-type: image/png');

 imagepng($im);
 imagedestroy($im);
 ?>
```

more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php)