# CSS 3D Transforms

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms, css-animations

I'm trying to create a 3D transform effect where a `<div>` folds into an airplane and flies off the screen.

To achieve this, I'm now creating multiple `<div>` elements - one for each fold - and then applying CSS 3D transformations to each one to transform into a paper airplane and then key-framing the whole thing to fly off the screen.

The issue is that I want to do the same on a div with user-inputted text on it  --- essentially I want the text in the div to fold too. There doesn't seem to be a way to do it using my method, because I'm splitting the page into divs for each fold...

Anyone know of any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could clone the node, cut it, and the clone, in half and then continue with the animations you're already doing.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rCAA4/

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <p class="text">
       ...your text goes here...
    </p>
</div>
```

..and javascript (jQuery):

```
var $box = $('.box'),
    $text = $('.text'),
    width_of_$box = $box.css('width'),
    half_width_of_$box = parseInt(width_of_$box)/2 + "px";

$text.css('width', width_of_$box);

$box.css({
    'width': half_width_of_$box,
    'overflow': 'hidden'
});

$box
    .clone()
    .find('.text')
        .css('margin-left', "-" + half_width_of_$box)
    .end().appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the overflow:hidden is the key here. In my case, I'll have the fold-divs created already. I just need to add text into all of them with the right margins and set the overflow to be hidden, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

You can probably convert the input text field to a canvas that stores the image after input. Then, program the canvas with javascript.

I never tried it, yet. But, I think it might work.

[Text to image on fly with javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292474/text-to-image-on-fly-with-javascript-or-jquery)